# c# documentation/comments for immutable type classes

Tags: c#, documentation, comments, tooltip

Hi is there any way to document the properties of an immutable type for a developer in c#?

I know you can easily document classes and objects itself with:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// This is an object
  /// </summary>
```

But how can I make an entry for the popupmenu if I create a new object:

```
Myobject ob1 = new Myobject(x1,x2,.....);
```

What I would like to have is a short description for each value, for example
"x1 is the length of my object" and "x2 is the height". Also I would like to add something responsive, for example if the user gave an "1" as input for x1, x2 shows the tooltip "Length", but if the user gave an "2" as input, x2 shows "height" in the tooltip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Above your constructor add this:

```
public class Myobject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new Myobject instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x1">The x1 parameter does something</param>
    /// <param name="x2">The x2 parameter does another thing</param>
    public Myobject(int x1, int x2)
    {}
}
```

For more availabe documentation tags see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments)